# ios App Local Notifications Not showing notification in production

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

This is my AppDelegate.swift file code:

I have called the showNotification() in here:

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {

    //call channel handler
    controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController
    callChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.nta.ntacall/calls",
                                              binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    callChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
        (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
        // Note: this method is invoked on the UI thread.
        guard call.method == "processCalls" else {
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            return
        }
        //process call test
        //self.processCalls()
    })

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    getLocation()
    /calling the show notification method here
    showNotification()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

I have this showNotification method here:

```
func showNotification(){
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    }
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    }
    //if not active state then show notification
    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .background {
        print("App in Background")
    }else if state == .active {
        print("App in Foreground or Active")
    }

    if state == .background {
        print("1")
        
        print("CXCallState :Disconnected")
        
        // Step 2: Create the notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Please rate your last call"
        content.body = "Tap to rate..."
        //show notification
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: nil)
        // Step 5: Register the request
        center.add(request) { (error) in
        // Check the error parameter and handle any errors
        }
    }
    else{
        processCalls()
    }
    
}
```

It is working fine in development and in emulator and real device but it is not showing notification while the app is published in app store?
What might be the reason?

Comment: Most probably your server sends pushes to the sandbox environment. Make sense to check errors there. Check certificates/profiles

Comment: But I am only using the local notification, no server involved? Certificate issue arise on the local notification too?

Comment: Authorization?
I do not see any difference between product ad sandbox environment for the local notifications.

Comment: That authorization code is just for asking permission to allow the notification. Should I also apply the certificate to get the local notification in production app?

Comment: Yes. You should create the certificate, update the app id and the project settings. Probably, I've never tried to raise a local notification without it.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it too but didn't work.